# Markdown: prevent page breaking

Tags: html, markdown, page-break

I have been using page breaks all over my document to make sure I don't have tables and entire sections broken with page breaks. But the document is very hard to manage this way. As it gets longer, more adjustments need to be made and I think it would be more efficient to declare "break here is not allowed" rather than "break here".

Can I do this is HTML/md?

**Update**:
I have been using HTML to insert page breaks into an .md document:

```html
<p style="page-break-after: always;">&nbsp;</p>
```

Comment: It's possible in CSS to tell the browser how to handle page breaks: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/break-inside

Comment: In markdown there are no page breaks. Because there are no "pages" in markdown.

Comment: @DanielW. I have updated my question to address your comment. Also, I'm going to attempt to experiment with `break-inside` to achieve the desired result

Comment: I haven't managed to achieve the desired result with neither break-after nor break-before

Comment: I'm wondering: What client/interpreter are you using?